# REST, WCF, CoreWCF or older Web Services (ASMX)

Tags: rest, wcf, maui, asmx, corewcf

I am an old ASP.NET WebForms developer using ASMX Web Services on an old Web System - maintaining for now as the client doesnt want to port at this stage.

Now I have started with .NET Maui which I love but will have to implement some Web API to access the company's database.

Obviously ASMX is old school but which would be the best alternative for .NET MAUI? I would like to avoid MVC as I first want to master MVVM and get used to it.

I am completely lost. Have done a lot of searching but cannot see which route to follow.

Appreciating all help

Comment: it's possible to make older ASMX services work, but it's incredibly painful and I would not recommend it.  Generally speaking any sort of RESTful service is much easier to work with.  The exact underlying technology isn't that important from the client perspective.

Comment: Thanks. .NET Core would be a great start it seems?

Comment: @Systellence get ASP.NET and web development for your VS 2022. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0 Read this for example.

Comment: Thanks. Has started with this and will implement the Minimal API. Easy and light.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share with you some experiences with [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF), Because I've had some little experiences with that. If you'd like to port your application to .NET Core without any effect on your clients (WSDL consumers), you can use CoreWCF. It's an unofficial package and a port of the service side of WCF to .NET Core. Obviously, for using CoreWCF, firstly you have to port your app to .NET Core and after that you can use CoreWCF. If your app doesn't need to be backward compatible with your WCF clients, you don't need to use CoreWCF.

Comment: Thank you so much. The app is written in .NET MAUI. In the meantime, I have developed the REST Minimal API which suites my needs - also compatible to different technologies which is a good thing.